# How to hide a div in .phtml if a customer is logged in magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks

I want to have a block in home page that show text and button if customer is not logged in and if he is logged in this block have to disapear so how to proceed any help please
here is my code in .phtml

```
<?php $objectManagerlogin = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); $customerSession = $objectManagerlogin->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session'); $baseurl = $objectManagerlogin->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore(0)->getBaseUrl(); ?> <?php if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) :?> <div class="title-home-page"> <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('You have to be a member to see the content of this Page!!! To be one of our members click <a href="%1" class="action submit primary">here</a>', $baseurl .'customer/account/create') ?> </div>
```

–

Answer (score 1):

Using the **object manager** directly seems easier but it's not the right way, you can see [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/117101/48355)

The right way is to inject for exemple `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session` in your block.

> app/code/Vendor/Name/Block/Blockname.php

```
protected $_session;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_session = $session;
    ...
}

public function isCustomerLoggedIn()
{
    return $this->_session->isLoggedIn();
}
```

Then in your phtml : (the file should be in the module)

```
<?php if (!$block->isCustomerLoggedIn()) : ?>
    <div>Your div content here</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In the case that your file is **not in the module** but in **template**, you can get it like this:

```
<?php $moduleBlock= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Name\Block\Blockname'); ?>

<?php if (!$moduleBlock->isCustomerLoggedIn()) : ?>
    <div>Your div content here</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If using Varnish cache or full page cache, building the logic inside the block will not work properly.

Take a look at the header, you will see Magento is using JS logic.

So, my suggestion is to use Ajax or based on local storage data.

In your case, I think you should use Ajax.

Comment: ok i tried but still not working can you please provide me more detail*

Comment: Could you update your question with what you're trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to show a ytext and a button in home page when a customer is not logged in and to hide them when he is connected

Comment: <?php
$objectManagerlogin = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManagerlogin->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$baseurl = $objectManagerlogin->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore(0)->getBaseUrl();
?>
<?php if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) :?>
    <div class="title-home-page">
    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('You have to be a member to see the content of this Page!!! To be one of our members click <a href="%1" class="action submit primary">here</a>', $baseurl .'customer/account/create') ?>
</div>

Comment: Please, update your question with that code.

Comment: please check my update question

Answer (score 0):

In home page template file, please check whether the customer logged in or not.

Following code you can check customer login or not anywhere

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer login action
}
```

From controller

```
$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer login action
}
```

Comment: yes i   used the first objectManager but not working

Comment: <?php if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) :?>
<div id="divId" class="not-logged-in">
    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Inscrivez-vous pour demander une pré-commande ou proforma members 
<a href="%1" class="action submit primary">souscrire</a>',
        $baseurl .'customer/account/create') ?>
</div>
<?php endif;?>

Comment: what error its showing

Comment: i just logged in and i still see the text and the button

Comment: <?php if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) :?> 
 <div id="divId" class="not-logged-in"> <?php echo 'something';?> </div> 
 <?php endif;?>
Try this to check whether you are having any syntax error

Comment: ok i will try  this example

Comment: i still the something text :(

Comment: i think that i have to create a new class css but i don't know how to do that and i tried this   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104382/add-css-class-to-body-if-the-customer-is-logged-in but string is not supported in my phpstorm any idea

Comment: i think that it'is an easy trick but why is't not working

Comment: can u pls share ur code

Comment: the .phtml or  whole module

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86727/discussion-between-kavitha-mano-and-developper-magento).

Comment: i just created a controller a simple block and route name log and then i put my code in .phtml to test on customer session