# Magento 2 Check out as legal entity

Tags: magento2, checkout

I am a beginner in Magento, and generally at using any CMS, so maybe some of these may seem obvious to you, but are not obvious at all to me.

What I need to do for my shop is create a system where, at checkout, clients can choose between checking out as an

- Individual => Normal checkout
- Legal Entity => Some new fields appear, such as Company Name, CUI, RO

Also, it would be useful to be able to store these for later use as well

**Note** I do not expect anyone to give me a full working system on a platter. But I would like some info on where to look to learn more about how to do this maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give you a high level explanation on what  I think you need to do but i think it's very custom and if you are not a developer I think you will have to hire one.

Create different customer groups for individual and entity

Use something like this to add body class

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/161651/70343

Bit instead logged in base it on logged in customer - Customer group

Add custom checkout fields as optional fields

Use css to show / hide fields depending on customer group. Won't work for guest checkout- so disable so guest

Comment: I am actually a developer, and I have a lot of experience with php (and have worked a lot with laravel), but I haven't worked with Magento before. But it is stunning for me to find out that adding custom fields to checkout is such a rare thing.

Comment: Welcome to the pain that is magento 2. Adding a field is quite an involved process https://github.com/DominicWatts/Postbox probably harder than it should be. But getting something to show and hide for different customer groups will require that css trick I explained

Comment: @domnic Xigen, I was wondering, wouldn't https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-custom-checkout-fields/ do the trick? Just add some custom fields and that's it?

Comment: Yes that's an option. Just realised I misunderstood and you want a dropdown where you can select what you are. I initially thought you wanted different fields depending on selection